# How to calculate page load time in percentage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, performance, page-load-time

I want to create a preloader that shows page loading in percentages. I know how to calculate page load time but i need this in percentage. how can i get the percentage of page loading time?

Comment: This is really weird question, you know how to calculate the loading time of a page (I don't know how to do that), but you can't do simple percent math (`elapsedTime / totalLoadingTime x 100`).

Comment: I said i need preloader. How do I know a website's elapsed time before page load?

Comment: Then why didn't you ask that? Unless you're loading the page using AJAX, you can't get the elapsed time. You could play with [readystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event) event of `document` , but that's too rough to calculate percents.

Comment: okay thank you. it means i cannot show page loading percentage on preloader with js.

Comment: That maybe depends on what you really have at hands, if you'd just show some code of this "preloader".